# please tell me why does the output of the two picture is different?

Tags: c, string

This program accept 5 string and print them.
here is the program:-

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"conio.h"
void main(){
    clrscr();
    char s[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%s", s[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("\n\n%s", s[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

when i execute this program the output will be this

[Click here to see the output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Iybg.png)

but when i enter the string in different way it print wrong output

[Click here to see the output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlKRI.jpg)

Comment: What's your code supposed to do? Why is the first correct but the second wrong? You can't just show code and pictures without telling us how it's *supposed* to work.

Comment: `char s[5];` --> `char s[5][32];`, `for(i=0;i<5;i++){` --> `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){`

Comment: 1. Please post the text and lot links to images of text. 2. Indent your code to make it readable. 3. What is the input

Comment: In `scanf("%s", s[i])` you're asking the compiler to generate code to read a string (the `"%s"`) and put that string in an invalid location (`s[i]` is a value of type `char`). You need to fix this (among other minor things)

Comment: @EdHeal "lot links" is really confusing. You obviously meant "not links"...

Comment: Yes realized it but unable to edit it as time ran out

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a string into a char, or rather, the string you read starts at the char position i in s. As `s` is very short (and when `i` is 5 it is empty), there will be an overflow, causing undefined behavior.

You want to have an array of strings, not of chars, as Blue Pixy mentions in his comment, e.g. `char s[5][32];`.

Also turn warnings on. The `i` in the second for loop is not defined.

Comment: Sorry to tell you but this is not the answer I expected

Comment: Well, user, the reason is that there is undefined behavior, which means the behavior is undefined and so it is very well possible that the output is wrong or different or that you get a seg fault or whatever. If you fix the errors of your program, it will give the output as expected. Undefined behavior cannot be reasoned about.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `s` as a 5-element array of `char`; each `s[i]` can store a *single* character value, not a string.  Since you don't explicitly initialize each `s[i]`, they contain an *indeterminate* value.

The argument corresponding to the `%s` specifier in `scanf` must have type `char *` (each `s[i]` has type `char`), and it must point to the first element of an *array* of `char` large enough to store the string contents (including the 0 terminator that marks the end of the string).

When you call

```
scanf( "%s", s[i] );
```

you're telling `scanf` to store the next *sequence* of non-whitespace characters to the address corresponding to the *value* stored in `s[i]`, which is a) indeterminate and b) likely not valid.  The resulting behavior is *undefined*, meaning pretty much anything can happen - your code may work as expected, it may crash outright, it may give you garbled output, it may corrupt other data, etc.

As written, `s` can store a string up to 4 characters long.

If you want to store an array of *strings*, then `s` needs to be a 2-dimensional array of `char`:

```
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20 // or however long you expect your longest string to be
...
char s[5][MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
```

Each `s[i]` can now store a string up to `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` characters.  The rest of your code should now behave as expected.